# extract and replace a token in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed, token

In a source code file, I need to change all the instances like

```
foo_bar('param')
```

to become

```
booch['param']=$param
```

Here, `param` is a token and it can vary. It can be anything.

i.e., in a file,

all the

```
foo_bar('xxx')
```

have to become

```
booch['xxx']=$xxx
```

and,

all the

```
foo_bar('yyy')
```

have to become

```
booch['yyy']=$yyy
```

and so on. I'm trying to do it by writing a shell script and using sed. But couldnt figure out how to do it. Hope my query is understandable. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed "s/foo_bar('\([^']*\)')/booch['\1']=$\1/g" infile > outfile
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "foo_bar('xxx')" | sed "s/foo_bar('\(.*\)')/booch['\1']=$\1/"
booch['xxx']=$xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same thing, using perl

```
cat yourfile.txt | perl -pe "s/(foo_bar)\(\s*('(\w*)')\s*\)/booch\[\$2\]=\\$\$3/" > youralteredfile.txt
```